# Selenium automator ramdonly timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to test ui.
We have several testcases to run. Everytime there's something timeout. Which one to fail on time is random and so is the number of failed ones. But my screen shots shows that the elements are actually rendered well.
If I run one by one, they are all successful.
I see it always happens at :

```
automator.waitForElementPresent(elemLocator, timeOutTime);
```

We are using version 2.28.0
Could anyone please give me some suggestion on this?
Thanks soooo much!!!

Comment: What driver? What OS? Are any test cases dependent on one-another? Do you have any pre-test setup information?

Comment: @Arran Under linux. The driver is selenium version 2.28.0. Those test cases are independent.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have often problems with Firefox of this sort. So i mainly run the tests in chrome. I start the selenium server with added param: -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=d:\programs\chromedriver.exe. Use your own location. Also, in the setUp() you need to specify chrome instead of firefox.

Comment: @qrazi Can you please put this in answer, so that I can select this one as best answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have often problems with Selenium / Firefox-combination of this sort. So I mainly run the tests in Chrome.

I am planning to use a stable environment for continuous integration using Jenkins, so I then can test on Firefox as well. As a sideline... :)

For my local development system I'm always running the latest Selenium, and the latest Firefox. So when I'm writing my Selenium tests, I use Chrome to run them.

I start the Selenium server with added param:

```
java -jar selenium.x.xx.x.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=d:\programs\chromedriver.exe
```

Use your own location. Also, in the setUp() of each test-class you need to specify "chrome" instead of "firefox" as the browser.